# creating a method that will be used to display query results on android sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

hi guys am creating android app that will be dealing with populating very long txts to the textViews(one per layout) so i have the helper class the utility and my normal activity classes. in the utility there is a method for displaying records which is to be called in the normal activity classes this method in the utility class is

```
... 
//here we go
public static void ShowMessageBox(Context cont, String msg) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(cont, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) ;
    // toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
//end of the method`
```

`

now i want that one instead of populating on the toast, to display on the text view help me how can i do this or how to create a method that will direct the cursor results to textviews

Comment: Are you really just asking how to set the text of a textView?  Its view.setText, after getting the view by findViewById.  The hard part is getting the data from the db, which you seem to have done.

Answer (score 0):

basically gabe sechan has said it.

delete the toaststuff.
add:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)((Activity)cont).findViewById(R.id.yourtextviewidfromxml);
tv.setText(msg);
```

Comment: i waa asking for a method that can be used to show deteils on the text view i solved that though